# Import excel (.xlsx) file data in android

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-poi

I have a problem regarding Excel(.xlsx) file import in Android SQLite database, I am using Poi jar file but finding following Runtime error.

- java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

How can i resolve this problem ? please help me.

Comment: Can you share your code Vikas ?

Comment: @selva this is line where i m getting mentioned exception... XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input); where 'input' FileinputStream class object

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven try the following

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

if not just download the jar file and add in your built path.

Comment: Hi, I already added these jar poi-3.14-20160307.jar,
poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar,
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar
in my project after that getting verifier error.

Answer (score 0):

Java on Android has some intricacies which require some more work due to duplicate classes in some jars, the number of methods that POI has and some javax.* code that is included via transitive dependencies.

There are multiple approaches that were used by others over time:

- Recently I prepared a sample at https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ which allows to build a combined jar-file which includes everything needed for Apache POI in a way that also works on Android
- The project at https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx tries to provide ready-made jar-files that are patched and adjusted to work on Android
- Previously for Android versions below 5, https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX did provide a slightly approach, still with ready-made jar-files being provided

Please try to use one of those and report back if you succeed. The first one is a rather new approach, but it would allow to re-package newer versions of Apache POI rather quickly compared to the other two which are a few versions behind already.

Comment: Hi, @Centic, I will test soon and give you feedback immediately, thanks for your response...

Comment: Hi Centic in above first link how to get poishadow-all.jar file?, second link is working fine but for min sdk 21, how ever my requirement is for min sdk 14-15, I think first link is fine but I am unable to find  poishadow-all.jar file, please help me.

Comment: See the instructions in the README at https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/: 

git clone git://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android
cd poi-on-android
./gradlew build

will build the shadow-jar as well

Comment: HI, Centic, when cloning project from Github get this error... " The SDK directory 'F:\Vikas_android\PoiAndroid\opt\android\android-sdk-linux' does not exist. Please fix the 'sdk.dir' property in the local.properties file" . While I am using same sdk path for all of my other project successfully..... and one thing more where to use term './gradlew build connectedCheck ' when clone ? plz help me

Comment: there is a local.properties file where you should put the location of your Android SDK. And the gradlew is the command to run Gradle, as you seem to use Windows you can try "gradlew.bat build" in the cloned directory.

Comment: I already set path in local.properties....... it also creating problem Error:(4, 43) error: package org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions does not exist
Error:(5, 1) error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
Error:(6, 37) error: package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist. this error is in compilation of your sample project.  Can you plz provide "poishadow-all.jar " manually ?

Comment: Found this exception "org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" when using poishadow-all.jar file. I set min sdk 15 max sdk 22 , also set "System.setProperty()..." in my main activity as us set in demo.

Comment: Please post this as issue on the github project together with the full stacktrace and some sample code and files required to reproduce it. Comments on answers in stackoverflow are not that well suited here.